# Why is window.onhashchange doesn't work in tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm learning Javascript, and I want to write a simple script in Tampermonkey, which will run when the URL fragment identifier changes.
But the following function doesn't work when the identifier change. `window.onhashchange` doesn't work either. I'm convinced that the `func()` is not the reason.

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function (){
    alert("run");
    func();
});
```

But if I add this function for testing,

```
window.addEventListener("click", function (){
   console.log(window.location.hash);
});
```

The hash printed in the console changes with the identifier every time I click, as expected.

I have no idea if this is my problem or the website or the Tampermonkey.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with Javascript, see

```js
function func() {
    console.log(window.location.hash);
}

window.addEventListener("hashchange", function (){
    func();
});
```

```html
<a href="#abc">first link</a>
<a href="#bcd">second link</a>
```